# Render data in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Hello I'm try to Render data in a component to another component, which are siblings to one another. **with useState Hook**(rff) based on component code (rcf)

```
index.js -> is entry point, that calls only one component App, as we have no route
App.js -> is the parent component, which has two child, Certification and Panel
Certification.js -> takes input
Panel -> renders data from certification
```

**I know i have problem with handleFromCert** (this is my handle change function)

here my code -rff

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-paper-gil-xcyj3?file=/src/

here the code that based on rcf and work fine

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-shtern-362ki?file=/src/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected the code and now it works!

1. `handleFromCert` in `App.js` should receive `name` and `value`;
2. `value2` in the `Panel` component in `App.js` is passed with an error;
3. `handleFromCert` in `Certifications.js` `setValue` changes incorrectly.

**Certifications.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Certifications = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    value1: "",
    value2: ""
  });

  const handleFromCert = ({ target: { value, name } }) => {
    setValue(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
    props.handleFromCert(name, value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input name="value1" onChange={handleFromCert} />
      <input name="value2" onChange={handleFromCert} />
      <div>
        Inside certificate
        <div>{value.value1}</div>
        <div>{value.value2}</div>
        Certificate ends
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Certifications;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Certifications from "./Certifications";
import Panel from "./Panel";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    value1: "",
    value2: ""
  });

  const handleFromCert = (name, value) =>
    setValue((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));

  return (
    <div>
      {value.value1}
      {value.value2}
      <Certifications handleFromCert={handleFromCert} />
      <Panel value1={value.value1} value2={value.value2} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Have you ever heard about <FormikStepper>?

Comment: Yes I heard. We recently started using Formik at work. So far I like everything

Comment: maby you can help my here also my dear friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63925561/formik-stepper-propshooks-between-steps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not passing the event as the argument, you're passing the value and your function is expecting the event. In your Certification component change this:

```
  const handleFromCert = (e) => {
   setValue({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
   });
   props.handleFromCert((e.target.name, e.target.value));
  };
```

To this:

```
  const handleFromCert = (e) => {
   setValue({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
   });
   props.handleFromCert(e);
  };
```

Your function handleFromCert is expecting the event, and you're just passing the value which is a string and cannot be destructured like the event.

Here's the sandbox working for me:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-paper-gil-forked-r01fh